# How to Install Linux via USB Flash Disk on Macbook

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a Macbook 2,1 
Processor 2.16 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo 
Memory 2GB 667 MHz DDR2 SDRAM
Mac OS X Version 10.6.8
Boot ROM Version MB21.00A5.B07
SMC Version (system) 1.17f0
HDD ST9120822AS : BSD Name: disk0
  Medium Type:  Rotational
  Partition Map Type:   GPT (GUID Partition Table)
  S.M.A.R.T. status:    Verified
  Volumes:
  Capacity: 209.7 MB (209,715,200 bytes)
  Writable: Yes
  BSD Name: disk0s1
MACINTOSH:
  Capacity: 119.69 GB (119,690,170,368 bytes)
  Available:    88.15 GB (88,153,722,880 bytes)
  Writable: Yes
  File System:  Journaled HFS+
  BSD Name: disk0s2
  Mount Point:  /

How to Install Linux with that spec, I have try many tutorial install Linux from USB flash disk with unebootin, refit, refind etc. 
Starting Legacy Loader
Using load options 'USB'
Error: Not Found returned from Legacy Loader
Error: Not Found from LocateDevicePath (x12 times)
Error: Load Error while (re)opening our Installation volume
The firmware refused to boot from the selected volume
Note that external hard drives are not well supported by Apple's firmware for legacy OS booting.

Answer (score 1):

your system configuration is good enough to install ubuntu, use [this link](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx)  for reference.

this may help you.

Comment: I've been take the macbook to service for install linux but they giving up with my machine. I've sell that Macbook then buy a new ASUS X205TA then have a new problem to Install 15.04 on it. Thanks for your answer Neel